# SSH connection issue on EC2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, tty

I have a really annoying problem with my server, even I couldn't find any search term to google it.

Let me explain it.

on my server I can connect to ssh using with ip address it is ok.

ex : `ssh -p2222 ubuntu@xx.xxx.xxx.xx`  It is working.

but I cannot login with domain name. SSH connects, it asks for password for user ubuntu but the password doesn't work.

ex : `ssh -p2222 ubuntu@domainname.com`  It is not working.

Comment: what IP does a DNS lookup for `domainname.com` return? Is it the same?

Comment: Your IP is registered to DNS server ??

Comment: what does `nslookup domainname` returns? does it show hte correct IP ?

Comment: @reto yes, it is, I checked through online dnslookup tool and also pinged from my computer to be sure is the same ip.

Comment: @RahulRDhobi yes it is also in same computer, I use bind.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer it returns correct IP. It is so wierd, I cannot connect and don't know what is the problem.

Comment: oh I see one interesting result when I type my password when connecting ssh, It returns "Permission denied, please try again."

Comment: provide the output of `ssh -p2222 ubuntu@domainname.com -vvv`

Comment: @slayedbylucifer I just shocked, I see line debug1: Connecting to yourdomain.com [::1] port 2222. It is so weird, there is no record on hosts file, I can connect my domain through scp, webbrowser and other things, but ssh it such a wierd.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you use same EC2 Key Pair when you start your instance.

Comment: I'm sure for that, I was using it without problems but I changed ssh port from 22 to 2222 and the problem occured after that. I opened port on ec2 dashboard security section, also changed from sshd_config. I restarted networking and sshd several times, rebooted machine, but doesn't worked.

Comment: If it is possible for you to connect on port 2222, your authentication problem shouldn't be related with changing ports 22 to 2222.